# Can't get Arabic data from Oracle db (select query) in Java

Tags: java, oracle

I want to retrieve a column value (varchar2) of a table in an Oracle database 11g which contains arabic names. But I am always getting "??????????" instead of the arabic name. Code snippet is given below:

```
public class DBConnection {
    
    private static final String DB_DRIVER_CLASS = "oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver";
    private static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.10.15.114:1521:ORCLCDB";
    private static final String DB_USERNAME = "sys as sysdba";
    private static final String DB_PASSWORD = "Oradoc_db1";
    
    public static Connection getDBConn() throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException, SQLException
    {
        Connection con = null;
        try {
            // load the Driver Class
            Class.forName(DB_DRIVER_CLASS);

            // create the connection now
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL+"?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=AL16UTF16", DB_USERNAME,DB_PASSWORD);
            //System.out.println("database connected successfully");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return con;
    }

}
```

```
 Connection oConn =null;
 Statement stmt =null;

 oConn = DBConnection.getDBConn();

 String sql = "select * from person_data";
 stmt = oConn.createStatement();
 ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);

 while (rs.next()) {

 String emp_name1 = rs.getNString("EMP_NAME");
 String emp_name2 = rs.getString("EMP_NAME");
 byte[] tmp = rs.getBytes("EMP_NAME");
 String emp_name3 = new String(tmp, "Windows-1256");

}
```

Example of a query:

```
"emp_name" like "اسامة محمد عبدالله توحيد احمد"
```

I tried three different ways(using getString, getNString) but nothing worked.
Can someone help me with this problem?

Comment: Can you add a sample record ?

Comment: @Prog_G yes sure .  "emp_name" like "اسامة محمد عبدالله توحيد احمد"

Comment: Have a look at [Database JDBC Developer's Guide - Globalization Support](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/JJDBC/global.htm#JJDBC28643)

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit Thanks .... already checked it but haven't got any solution

Comment: @Prog_G any suggestion regarding the issue?